# Unable to insert TYPE_BODY_FAT_PERCENTAGE in google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I was trying to insert body fat percentage in google fit history but `insertStatus.isSuccess()` returns false, Below is my code

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        // Create a data source
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName(this)
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_BODY_FAT_PERCENTAGE)
                .setName(TAG + " - body fat")
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build();

        // Create a data set
        float value = 20;
        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
        DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
                .setTimestamp(endTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
//                .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_PERCENTAGE).setFloat(value);
        dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

And below the insert data code

```
   Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API");
            com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
                    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                            .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

            // Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded.
            if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: can u pls post your inserData code ?

Comment: @  Android Weblineindia Updated code

Answer (score 1):

I thing you can directly add value in data point cause `TYPE_BODY_FAT_PERCENTAGE` doesn't have any subtype fields .Like below .

```
dataPoint.setFloatValues((Float) values)
```